# Windows phone get server source code

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I am trying to get the source code of a site. In windows application a simple http request would be enough. However in windows phone it is a lot more complicated.
I searched a lot on google and didn't come with a clear answer.
This is what I tried but without big success.

```
public static sReturn = "";

private string _InetGetSourceCode(string sUrl)
{
   _InetReadEx(sUrl);
   return sReturn;
}

private void _InetReadEx(string sUrl)
{
   WebClient client = new WebClient();

   client.DownloadStringCompleted += new    
   DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCallback2);
   client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(sUrl));
}

private static void DownloadStringCallback2(Object sender,DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
   {
      sReturn = e.Result;
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by *"without big success"*?

Comment: I was Just scrapping samples and nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Not seemed to work, like... Exceptions? All data in caps? Encoding issue? Timeouts? Exploding phone? High score of Whats-App erased? If you can't produce a clear explanation of the problem, how are we going to give a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you return `sReturn` immediately, but the download won't complete until some time in the future. So `sReturn` still has the default value of the empty string at the time you return it.

You can download [this sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/HTTP-and-Socket-API-e38ac69e) which includes code for doing exactly what you want to do using the `HttpClient` portable library.

Comment: @Petter that makes sense. I followed the link and got lost.
I have never used async method. I will try getting it work and come back.
Thank you

Comment: @Maria *async* is not a one off methodology. Development on Silverlight/Windows Phone uses the async paradigm to access data regardless of what the operation needs happen to be. For some *live* examples see Lucian Wishik's (Microsoft) [Async Silverlight sync Samples](http://wischik.com/lu/AsyncSilverlight/AsyncSamples.html) which will easily lend themselves to the WP8 platform.

Comment: Try this video for an intro to `async` programming: [Understanding Async and Awaitable Tasks](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-28-Understanding-Async-and-Awaitable-Tasks)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the correct answer to my question:
Big thanks to @Peter Torr - MSFT for the help that leaded me to the exact answer of my problem

**Answer**

```
    public static sReturn = "";
    public async Task _InetReadEx(string sUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(sUrl));
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                //sStatus = response.StatusCode + " " + response.ReasonPhrase + Environment.NewLine;
                sSource = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                sSource = sSource.Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine); // Insert new lines
            }
            catch (Exception hre)
            {
                sSource = string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

and the way to call it:

```
    public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Task.Run(async () => { await _InetReadEx("http://url.com/"); }).Wait();
        }
```

Big thanks to everyone and the community!